# How to skip a row of zeros with np.loadtxt?

Tags: python, numpy, txt

I have a .txt file that contains many rows of numeric values. Each row looks as follows
`3.896784 0.465921 1.183185 5.468042 ...`, where the values differ depending on the row.

Furthermore, every row contains 900 values.
Some rows do not contain real data, but only 900 zeros as follows
`0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...`.

I know how to skip rows that only contain one value, i.e., one zero, such as via the following code:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt("pathtodata")
data = data[~(data==0)]
```

But this code does not work for 2 zero values or more per row. Is there a way to not load rows that only contain 900 or any arbitrary number of zeros (or a specific integer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt("data.txt")
data = data[~np.all(data == 0, axis=1)]


for row in data:
    print(row)
```

Should do the trick, `np.all(data == 0, axis=1)` is essentially what you are asking for, it checks if every element in a given row verify a condition, here you exclude every row where every element are equal to 0

Comment: Thank you. I accept your answer, because it solves the problem within just one line of code! Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.any` to do that. It will check if there are any values other than 0 along a certain axis. So it will return `False` when a row is all zeros. Then you can use the ouptut of this to subset your dataset:

```
import numpy as np

test = np.arange(20).reshape((4,-1))
test[0,:] = 0
print(test)
mask = np.any(test, axis=1)
print(test[mask,:])
```